# Get childobject with child id = x if unknown parents

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

So, consider the following data structure:

```
{
  "speed" : {
    "scores" : {
      "aHOBsddilrQ2lX3fal8v" : {
        "RrbEpWwfEAeVpnbXabSP" : {
          "event" : 959140,
          "judge" : "Svante",
          "zETdMyzb2OWgrVq9GJwv" : {
            "score" : 65,
            "timestamp" : 1466355355
          },
          "Jd0wtYEs74A2wc47LI7F" : {
            "score" : 75,
            "timestamp" : 1466355465
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the score of the deepest child with the newest timestamp's score if I know `authuid` and the value of `event:` but neither of the randomid's (both are unique)

I've tried different approaches with `for ()` and `.orderBy[Child|Key|Value]().equalTo().limitToLast(1);` (none of which looks good enough to even bother sharing...) which didn't work. I have one extremely dirty and hacks solution currently that'll break if I add one more value to the second deepest part of the tree (using `for` and `.length - 3`) is there a way to do this cleaner?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen well I know about that, I've been using firebase since it's release but more serious now since v3... I saw some others using images and thought maybe that was praxis on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Database can query nested children, but only if you know the path. What you are looking for goes a bit beyond Firebase's querying capabilities, which always have to balance query power with the realtime nature of the database.

As usual with NoSQL databases, the solution is to change the data model to suit your needs. For this case, I'd set up a node that has the latest score for each event under that event's id:

```
{
  "speed" : {
    "mostRecentScoresPerEvent" : {
      "event959140": {
        "score" : 75
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can update the score with a simple set operation:

```
ref.child('speed/mostRecentScoresPerEvent/event'+eventId).set(42);
```

And read it using:

```
ref.child('speed/mostRecentScoresPerEvent/event'+eventId).on('value',...
```

Comment: well the problem here kinda is that
a) There'll be between 1 and twelve simultaneous different scores by different people at the same time, permission rule-wise that would be quite tricky to work with in your example,
b) on the other hand i have a page where the uid is caught and stored, is there a way to catch the names of the two deeper levels, because on that page i've for looped all childs of all uid childs to let the user select. using $id only works on the outer layer of the data tough

Comment: maybe an approach more like this? {
  "speed" : {
    "scores" : {
      "aHOBsddilrQ2lX3fal8v" : {
        "959140" : {
          "judge" : "Svante",
          "1466355355" : {
            "score" : 65,
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}